running cronjob every 6 hrs - multiple jobs at different hours
I have the same sort of job for 10 parallel postgres instances on a single server. They should run every 6 hours, but not all at the same hours.
11 */6 * * * my_command runs at 0:11, 6:11, 12:11, 18:11
So I can pull them apart from each other with the means of defining the minute (so 30 minutes max). But I would like more, like running 0,6,12,18 vs running i.e. 2,8,14,20
so my question is ... is there a way to have another job running i.e. 2:11, 8:11, 14:11, 20:11
or do I have to say 11 */6 * * * sleep 120m && my_command for the alternative execution?

Well, just use 2,8,14,20 in the hour field (0,6,12,18 is more portable than */6 btw)

true, sorry I have had a blockage on that part of da brain. If you posted that as an answer I would mark it as solution.

Using 0,6,12,18 or 2,8,14,20 is the standard way to specify those lists of hours. */6, though supported by most cron implementations is not standard.
So here, just use:
11 0,6,12,18 * * * my_command
22 2,8,14,20 * * * my_other_command

See also sleep "$((120 * 60))" or sleep "$((2 * 60 * 60))" for the standard equivalent of sleep 120m or sleep 2h.
Having said that, with the cron implementation found on Debian and derivatives at least, you can also combine range and interval so you should be able to do:
11    */6 * * * my_command
22 2-23/6 * * * my_other_command

(or use 0-23 in place of * in the first one to make it clearer what's different between the two).
